# Thread with XmlDocument as parameter

Tags: c#, xml, multithreading, parameters

Is it possible to send a XmlDocument as parameter in a Thread?

Follow code works

```
 Thread threadSendMessage = new Thread(sendController.SendData);
 threadSendMessage.Start(TestController.TestFilelocation4001);
```

...

```
internal void SendData(object filename) 
{
  XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
  xmlDocument.Load((string)filename);  
  Byte[] sendBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xmlDocument.OuterXml);  
  ConnectionSetupModel.UdpClient.Send(sendBytes, sendBytes.Length);
}
```

The following code does not work: 
Error: *The best overloaded method match for ’ System.Threading.Thread.Thread(System.Threading.ThreadStart)’ has som invalid arguments*

```
internal static XmlDocument TestFilelocation4000()
{
  XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
  xmlDocument.Load(TestFilelocation4000);
  return xmlDocument;
}
```

...

```
Thread threadSendMessage2 = new Thread(sendController.SendData2);
XmlDocument xmlDoc = TestController.TestFilelocation4000;
threadSendMessage2.Start(xmlDoc);
```

...

```
internal void SendData2(XmlDocument xmlDocument) 
{
  Byte[] sendBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xmlDocument.OuterXml);
  ConnectionSetupModel.UdpClient.Send(sendBytes, sendBytes.Length);
}
```

Is it only possible to send XmlDocument as Thread parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following to pass an XmlDocument to a method started within a new Thread:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = TestController.TestFilelocation4000;
var t = new Thread(() => sendController.SendData2(xmlDoc));
t.Start();
```

Answer (score 2):

The constructor of `Thread` expects a `ParameterizedThreadStart` delegate, with the following signature:

```
void ParameterizedThreadStart(object obj);
```

So you need to make sure that SendData2 takes an `object` as argument, like this (you did that correctly in your first method already):

```
internal void SendData2(object xmlDocument) 
{
  Byte[] sendBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(((XmlDocument)xmlDocument).OuterXml);
  ConnectionSetupModel.UdpClient.Send(sendBytes, sendBytes.Length);
}
```

Comment: Floele your code works fine, but I preference to use the SendData2 method with argument XmlDocument. Because it is easier to see, what kind of parameter the SendData2 method take. I use the Lambda thread instead.